# Get OpenTok stream by ID

Tags: opentok

I am creating an app where I want a specific stream to be shown big on another page. There will be one page with all the streams (subscriptions) and one page which will show a SPECIFIC stream on the whole screen.

1. Send the streamID of a chosen stream to the database.
2. On the other page, fetch the last added streamID in the database
3. Get stream by ID and show it on the page

I got the first two steps working, the last step is a problem. I somehow need to fetch a stream object by the given streamId. Is this possible? OR is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is the correct way to do it but you can add all the stream objects in an array:

```
var streamContainer = [];
session.on("streamCreated", streamCreatedHandler);

streamCreatedHandler = function(e) {
    streamContainer.push(e.stream)
}
```

and when your ID gets fetched unsubscribe from current, iterate over the array and subscribe to the new stream:

```
for(var i = 0; i < streamContainer.length; i++) {
    if(streamContainer[i].id == dbStreamId) {
        session.subscribe(streamContainer[i], 'DOMELEMENT', {options});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A few tips for you:
1. streamContainer = {} will help you reduce your code. You can set the streamId as key and stream object as value. This way, when you look up the stream you can simply do streamContainer[streamId].
2. The OP needs a database to store the stream so your suggestion will not work for his use case.

Comment: This is (almost) the same approach as I've been using.. I use the session.on(streamCreated) and check if a given ID matches the streamId. If so, subscribe to it. But where in your code do you unsubscribe from the current stream?

Comment: When the stream gets disconnected, it automatically because unsubscribed from the session. You can also listen to streamDestroyed event. Or manually call session.unsubscribe(stream) if you want to stop viewing user.

Answer (score 0):

You might not even need a database for what you are trying to do. Simply connect both pages (specific stream and all streams) to the same sessionId. You can put streamId in your url as a parameter like this: ?streamId=1343-thneue...

In your streamCreated event, simply check the stream.streamId in your callback function with your url streamId. If they match, then call session.subscribe on that stream object.

Comment: The reason I need a database is because the "big screen" checks every 5 seconds if the last added record matches the current streamId. If not, it refreshes the page and shows the new stream.

Comment: Ic. Your code might look something like this (syntax might not be correct):

$.get("/getLastStream.json", function(res){ if(res.streamId != currentStreamId){session.unsubscribe(allStreams[currentStreamId]); session.subscribe(allStreams[res.streamId]); }});